# Multishipping Checkout Progress Labels

Tags: checkout

i have looked everywhere i can think of and cant figure out how to change the wording of the labels in the progress checkout for multishipping.

where are the `<?php foreach ($this->getSteps() as $_step): ?>`
steps defined?

Comment: In which file is this code fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSteps()` is defined in `Mage_Checkout_Block_Multishipping_State` and it looks like this:

```
public function getSteps()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_multishipping_state')->getSteps();
}
```

This means it is a wrapper for `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Multishipping_State::getSteps()`.
The steps are defined in the constructor of the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Multishipping_State` class:

```
    $this->_steps = array(
        self::STEP_SELECT_ADDRESSES => new Varien_Object(array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Select Addresses')
        )),
        self::STEP_SHIPPING => new Varien_Object(array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Shipping Information')
        )),
        self::STEP_BILLING => new Varien_Object(array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Billing Information')
        )),
        self::STEP_OVERVIEW => new Varien_Object(array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Place Order')
        )),
        self::STEP_SUCCESS => new Varien_Object(array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Order Success')
        )),
    );
```

But I think the best idea to change their labels would be to use the locale file.

Look for the text `Place Order` (as an example) in `app/locale/{lang_ISO}/Mage_Checkout.csv` and change it's translation to anything your need.

Comment: will this change that language anywhere its found in checkout though, or just in the steps?

Comment: It will be changed everywhere in the checkout module. If you don't want that you can rewrite `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Multishipping_State` and change the steps text

Comment: i did this and dumped cache and it did nothing to the states

Comment: ignore the previous, my bad, it works